# Error while compilinga C file in RHEL server

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions

```
$ gcc -c exsystem.c
    In file included from exsystem1.c:39:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/varargs.h:4:2: error: #error "GCC no longer implements <varargs.h>."
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/varargs.h:5:2: error: #error "Revise your code to use <stdarg.h>."
exsystem1.c: In function âex_fprintfâ:
exsystem1.c:118: error: expected declaration specifiers before âva_dclâ
exsystem1.c:152: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â{â token
exsystem1.c:174: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â{â token
exsystem1.c:194: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â{â token
exsystem1.c:216: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â{â token
exsystem1.c:237: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â{â token
exsystem1.c:261: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âva_dclâ
exsystem1.c:293: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â{â token
exsystem1.c:312: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â{â token
exsystem1.c:336: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âva_dclâ
exsystem1.c:364: error: expected â{â at end of input
```

> These are the error's that i get when i run this code 
>   Below is the snippet of code which has errors:
>   Could someone help me in rewriting this code according to stdarg.h new implementation.

```
void ex_fprintf( va_alist )
va_dcl
{
   va_list   args;
   FILE    * fp;
   char    * fmt;
   va_start( args );
   fp = va_arg( args, FILE * );
   fmt = va_arg( args, char * );
   if ( vfprintf( fp, fmt, args ) == EOF )
   {
      va_end( args );
      perror( "fprintf" );
      Raise( Ex_fprintf );
   }
   va_end( args );
   return;

}
void ex_printf( va_alist )
va_dcl
{
   va_list   args;
   char    * fmt;
   va_start( args );
   fmt = va_arg( args, char * );
   if ( vprintf( fmt, args ) == EOF )
   {
      va_end( args );
      perror( "printf" );
      Raise( Ex_printf );
   }
   va_end( args );
   return;

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://systemmanager.ru/svcsunix.en/extfile/portapps/stdargvsvarargs.htm

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is similar, but the primary difference is that **stdarg** requires at least one named argument as a stopping place when looping through the arguments on the stack.

Refer to this link which explains it with examples: http://systemmanager.ru/svcsunix.en/extfile/portapps/stdargvsvarargs.htm

---

> #### stdarg vs. varargs
>
> Rather than conflict with the historical routines in **varargs.h**, the International Standards
>   Organization/American Standards Institute (ISO/ANSI) C standard
>   defines a new mechanism for dealing with variable argument lists,
>   **stdarg.h**. The **varargs** mechanism uses a magic name (**va_alist**) for the first argument in a list; **stdarg** uses the
>   last required argument. This means that **stdarg** must have at least
>   one named parameter.
>
> Usually, you can translate from **varargs** to **stdarg** easily,
>   because most functions with variable argument lists have a known
>   first-argument type. The following example is a trivial,
>   error-printing function that uses the **varargs** mechanism:
>
> ```
> #include <varargs.h>
> printerror( va_alist );
>
> void printerror (va_alist )
> va_dcl
> {
>    va_list ap;
>    char *fmt;
>    va_start(ap);
>    fmt = va_arg(ap, char *);
>    vprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
>    va_end(ap);
> }
> ```
>
> Because the function uses a format string as its first argument, you can easily use it as the known argument:
>
> ```
> #include <stdarg.h>
> void printerror (char *fmt, ...)
> {
>    va_start(ap, fmt);
>    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
>    va_end(ap);
> }
> ```
>
> You must give the first argument a name, even when the routine takes a
>   terminated list and no fixed arguments. For example, the following
>   function prints a set of strings, but the first argument is entirely
>   artificial, created to meet the needs of the **stdarg** package:
>
> ```
> #include <stdarg.h>
> pr_str(char *first, ...)
> {
>    char * current;
>    va_list argp;
>    va_start(argp,first);
>    current = first;
>    while (current != NULL){
>    fputs(current,stdout);
>    current = va_arg(argp, char *);
>    }
>    va_end(argp);
> }
> ```

Comment: void ex_fprintf( char * fmt, ... )
   {
  
      va_list   args;
      FILE    * fp;
      
  
      va_start( args, fmt );
  
      fp = va_arg( args, FILE * );
  
      fmt = va_arg( args, char * );
  
      if ( vfprintf( fp, fmt, args ) == EOF )
      {
         va_end( args );
         perror( "fprintf" );
         Raise( Ex_fprintf );
      }
        va_end( args );
        return;
     }i have changed the code but it doesnt seem to work